# Data getting overwritten in for loop for new and previous values

Tags: java, loops

I want tov compare previous and new value coming from a loop and based on data increment some rows.For that i am doing like below but the data is getting overwritten since i am doing inside for loop.How can i perform this.

```
    for (RecordData recordData : recordDataList) {      
        prevRespondentId = recordData.getRespondentId();
        if (recordData.getRespondentId() != prevRespondentId) {
             rowDataNumber++;
        }
        prevRespondentId = recordData.getRespondentId();
    }
```

I have data like 1,2,3 as respondent Id ,i need to see new and prev based on that increment data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this fix your issue?

```
    prevRespondentId = recordDataList.get(0).getRespondentId(); //Initialize to first or default value probably -1?

    for (RecordData recordData : recordDataList) {
                if (recordData.getRespondentId() != prevRespondentId) {
                rowDataNumber++;
            }
            prevRespondentId = recordData.getRespondentId();
        }
```

Basically you are overwriting the prevRespondentId even before checking for it, which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand what your trying to do however perhaps something like this:

```
for (RecordData recordData : recordDataList) {
        if (recordData.getRespondentId() != prevRespondentId) {
            rowDataNumber++;
        }
        prevRespondentId = recordData.getRespondentId();
}
```

Basically don't override the preRespondentId until you've done your if check. This will ensure that it will always be the previous respondent id. You'll of course need to initialise it though.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ..some type.. prevRespondentId = -1;
 for (RecordData recordData : recordDataList) {
     if (recordData.getRespondentId() != prevRespondentId) {
         rowDataNumber++;
     }
     prevRespondentId = recordData.getRespondentId();
 }
```